# How to get rows having different value from another table

Tags: sql

I have table with Invoice and Product columns.
One invoice can sell multiple product.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOY7U.png)
What I'm trying to do is retrieve the invoice which sell "A" and "B".
Thank you so much

Comment: Please don't post links to images of text — put the data in the question, possibly as a [table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/15168).  See also [How to make tables in questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220127/15168).

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we need to see your SQL so we can help you debug it. Writing it from scratch is not what we do here.

Comment: You will need to do a self-join on the table — which should have a name.  It is surprising how often people asking questions forget to give the names of the tables they're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Try This
taking count of unique products for a invoice where products in ('A','B')  which should be 2.

```
    SELECT INVOICE FROM (
    SELECT INVOICE,COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT) AS CNT FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE PRODUCT IN 
    ('A','B') 
    GROUP BY INVOICE
    ) T 
    WHERE CNT=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Invoice INT, Product NVARCHAR(1))

INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES (1,'A'),(1,'B'),(1,'C'),(2,'A'),(1,'C')

;WITH prA
AS (SELECT Invoice 
    FROM #tmp WHERE Product='A'),
    prB AS (SELECT Invoice
        FROM #tmp WHERE Product ='B')
SELECT *
FROM prA
JOIN prB ON prA.Invoice = prB.Invoice
```